# Wordpress/WooCommerce Products per row

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I've previously been trying to set products per row the ordinary way by simply setting it the number of products per row in the woocommerce shortcode. This however did not work. So I was given the code to enter in fuctions.php
Code below:

```
    // Change number or products per row to 3
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns');
if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {
    function loop_columns() {
        return 3; // 3 products per row
    }
}
```

This did solve the issue as seen on this [here](http://www.fonster24.tk/webshop). However if the number of products (it seems) exceeds 3 when using the products category shortcode I get a different result entirely. Seen [here](https://www.fonster24.tk/ytterdorrar/63mm-ytterdorrar/), if you scroll down a bit you can see that on the first row I get 3 products, but then 1, then 2 and then 1 again?

I find it all very strange and I would appriciate any help I can get! Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

On first page - the one which is working correctly - the "< li >" element has class "col-md-4 col-sm-6" but on the incorrect page, you have class "col-md-3 col-sm-4".

Comment: Ok I see, thanks. Is there a way to change it via CSS?

Comment: You should be missing something in configuration or so. Where you can define number of columns. Ideally that hook should work for you.